# Android: Workmanager getWorkInfoByTagLiveData, convert getWorkInfosByTagLiveData to single LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

When working with `Workmanager`, I faced the problem, that I wanted to get a `single LiveData Object` with the associated `tag`. My problem was, that `Workmanager` only provided `getWorkInfosByTagLiveData`.

Is there a way to get a single LiveData object with the associated tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the simple solution:

### Get single WorkInfo as Flow (to observer from ViewModel)

```
val singleWorkInfoAsFlow: Flow<WorkInfo> =
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).getWorkInfosByTagLiveData("TAG").asFlow().map { it[0] }
```

### Get single WorkInfo as LiveData (to observe from View)

```
val singleWorkInfoAsLiveData: LiveData<WorkInfo> =
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).getWorkInfosByTagLiveData("TAG").map { it[0] }
```

I know that this was not that hard, but I hope I helped some people with this. If someone knows the java version, just provide it here.

Cheers